# Diminuindo o código com php

Tags: php

Boa tarde, não sei se isso é uma boa prática mas andei olhando na net e percebi que assim em uma pagina html tem

chama o menu php
conteudo e fecha

e estou tentando fazer isso com o menu, head e o rodape

segue o codigo abaixo:

home.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<?php include("complemento/head.php"); ?>

<body>
    <span><a href="#" class="subir"><div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up aoredor"></div></a></span>
    <?php include("complemento/menu.php");?>

    <section class="home-head baixo-menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="bloco-home texto-centro col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="descricao-titulo texto-centro">Beleza e Harmônia</h1>


                    <div id='cont' class="digitar descricao-slide"></div>
                    <script>
                        digita('cont', "Transformando uma princesa em uma rainha!");
                    </script>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section>

            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="slide-home">
                        <div class="container conteudo-slides">
                            <div class="row margin-top20">
                                <h4 class="texto-centro ti-slide">Beleza e Harmônia proporciona pacotes incriveis para cortes de cabelos, escova, maquiagem, manicure e pedicure e muito mais...!</h4>
                                <p class="info-aviso texto-centro sub-titu">Confira abaixo</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 texto-centro">
                                <a href="agendamento.php">
                                    <button type="button" class="botao-slide">Quero ver os planos</button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="slide-segundo">
                        <div class="container conteudo-slides">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 texto-centro margin-top20">
                                <h4 class="ti-slide">Modelos sencionais que nosso salão proporciona...</h4>
                                <a href="Galeria.html">
                                    <button type="button" class="botao-slide">Que tal ver alguns modelos?</button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="item">
                    <div class="slide-terceiro">
                        <div class="container conteudo-slides">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 texto-centro margin-top20">
                                <h4 class="ti-slide">Conhece <i>Beleza e Harmônia</i>? Não então veja quem somos e por que você deve confiar em nós diantes dos cortes que você deseja.</h4> 
                                <p class="sub-titu">Confia abaixo!</p>

                                <a href="Sobre.html">
                                <button type="button" class="botao-slide">Visualizar o local</button>
                                    </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="preco">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 conteudo-planos">
                    <h3>Promoções</h3>
                    <p class="info-aviso">Beleza e Harmônia proporciona pacotes incriveis para cortes de cabelos, escova, maquiagem, manicure e pedicure e muito mais...!</p>
                    <p class="info-aviso">Confira abaixo</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="bloco-preco center-block fundo-home">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row center-block">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 tabela-promocaos efeito-precos">
                        <h4 class="dourado">Best Fried</h4>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <p class="item preto">Escova</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Hidratação</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Maquiagem</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Corte</p>
                        <p class="item preto">pintura</p>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <p class="bold preto">Nivel</p>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <p class="valor-texto preto"><span class="icone-valor preto">R$ </span>100</p>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <a href="agendamento.php">
                            <button class="botao-compra-preto">Marcar uma visita</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 tabela-promocaos efeito-precos">
                        <h4 class="dourado">Best Fried</h4>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado"/>

                        <p class="item preto">Escova</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Hidratação</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Maquiagem</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Corte</p>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <p class="bold preto">Nivel</p>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <p class="valor-texto preto"><span class="icone-valor preto">R$ </span>150</p>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <a href="agendamento.php">
                            <button class="botao-compra-preto">Marcar uma visita</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 tabela-promocaos efeito-precos borda-home">
                        <h4 class="dourado">Best Fried</h4>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <p class="item preto">Escova</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Hidratação</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Maquiagem</p>
                        <p class="item preto">Corte</p>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado"/>

                        <p class="bold preto">Nivel</p>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <p class="valor-texto preto"><span class="icone-valor preto">R$ </span>200</p>
                        <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                        <a href="agendamento.php">
                            <button class="botao-compra-preto">Marcar uma visita</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row center-block">

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 bloco-1 tabela-promocao efeito-preco">
                    <h4>Best Fried</h4>
                    <hr />

                    <p class="item preto">Escova</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Hidratação</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Maquiagem</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Corte</p>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <p class="bold preto">Nivel</p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <p class="valor-texto preto"><span class="icone-valor preto">R$ </span>250</p>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <a href="agendamento.php">
                        <button class="botao-compra">Marcar uma visita</button>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 bloco-1 tabela-promocao efeito-preco">
                    <h4>Best Fried</h4>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <p class="item preto">Escova</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Hidratação</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Maquiagem</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Corte</p>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <p class="bold preto">Nivel</p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <p class="valor-texto preto"><span class="icone-valor preto">R$ </span>300</p>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <a href="agendamento.php">
                        <button class="botao-compra">Marcar uma visita</button>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 bloco-1 tabela-promocao efeito-preco">
                    <h4>Best Fried</h4>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <p class="item preto">Escova</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Hidratação</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Maquiagem</p>
                    <p class="item preto">Corte</p>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <p class="bold preto">Nivel</p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <p class="valor-texto preto"><span class="icone-valor preto">R$ </span>350</p>
                    <hr class="linha-dourado" />

                    <a href="agendamento.php">
                        <button class="botao-compra">Marcar uma visita</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

 <?php include("complemento/rodape.php"); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

arquivo head.php:

```
<?php
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Studio 7 Hair é um salão de beleza">
    <meta name="author" content="Miyomic">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Beleza e Harmônia</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Imagens/favicon.png" type="image/x-png" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/visual.css">

    <!-- responsivo -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryAtualizado.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Fim responsivo -->

    <script src="js/digitar-home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/subir.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
?>
```

e assim por diante mas quando vou abrir ele... me apresenta esse erro:

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp64\www\Projeto Beleza e Harmonia\Beleza e Harmonia - site\complemento\head.php on line 2
```

e na linha dois do head.php é: `<html>`

Por que está acontecendo isso, o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nao tas a fexar o php basta apagar a primeira linha